# Can I print MS Access report without having to open it?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a bunch of reports in my MS Access dbs. Each report has an On Open event set up. It is to make it a little bit dynamic, it opens a form and asks the user what State he wants to generate the report for. This is all good.
But, I also need to print all of the reports for all states once a quarter. I can loop through all states and pass the variable to the report, but to print it, it seems like I have to always open it, which fires the On Open event. I don't want that. I could probably disable the On Open event and then open it and print it, but still, I am wondering, is there a way to print a report without opening it first?

Comment: You could use OpenArgs to skip the form opening if openArgs = "ForPrint" for example. But I think that on_open events always fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docmd.openreport "reportName", acViewNormal
```

sends the report straight to the printer.

Comment: No, it still fires the On Open event.